Creating multiplate booking instances from django booking form using .SelectMultiple()
    widgets = {
        'check_in_date': forms.DateInput(),
        'check_out': forms.DateInput(),
        'name': forms.SelectMultiple(),
    }

I can't figure out how to use the multi selector in my form to create multiple instances of my booking model. I want to be able to select the dates, pick multiple names from a list and then when clicking book, register a booking instance for each of the names selected that stores the current logged in user, the selected room and the check in and check out date selected in the form. I am continuously going in a loop of the same errors. Can anyone help me?
I've tried multiple ways of doing this like creating a list for the selected names before processing the data. the method that i sem to have got the furthest with so far is iterating over a for loop:
bookings = []
for name in selected_names:
booking = {
.....
}
bookings.append(booking)
for booking in bookings:
Booking.objects.set(**booking_data)
Booking.objects.save()
